# Java: find Id By Title () from models

Tags: java, android

This is my function, to find a `id` from `list` by matching `titles`

```
 public static int findIdByTitle(List<Integer> IDs, List<String> Titles ,String title){

    for (int i = 0; i < IDs.size(); i++){
        if (Titles.get(i).equals(title))
            return IDs.get(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function search in `model list` and find `id`

But I can't use this because:

```
int id = findIdByTitle(Core.userSignIn.getBasicList().getGradeList().get(****?****).getID()
                ,Core.userSignIn.getBasicList().getGradeList().get(****?****).getName()
                ,spinnerGrade.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

I must give it a number position : `(  see the lists.get(****?****).getID()` or `getName()`

I want **using that's function for all models** not just for this model
    give 2 `lists` and a matching word, use matching word to find position of that's  in `list`, and give me a `ID` of this position

All of my model have **ID** , **Title** and some of them have **ParentID**

---

with help of Nitin , My problem has been resolved:

```
            List<String> Titles = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Integer> IDs = new ArrayList<>();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                Titles = Core.userSignIn.getBasicList().getGradeList().stream().map(GradeList::getGradeName).collect(Collectors.toList());
                IDs = Core.userSignIn.getBasicList().getGradeList().stream().map(GradeList::getGradeID).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else {
                Titles = new ArrayList<>(Core.userSignIn.getBasicList().getGradeList().size());
                IDs = new ArrayList<>(Core.userSignIn.getBasicList().getGradeList().size());
                for (GradeList gradeList : Core.userSignIn.getBasicList().getGradeList()) {
                    Titles.add(gradeList.getGradeName());
                    IDs.add(gradeList.getGradeID());
                }
            }
            educationList1.setiGradeID(findIdByTitle(IDs
                    ,Titles
                    ,spGrade.getSelectedItem().toString()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to convert your list to List of Integer and List of String and then pass it to your method. You can use below code if you are using Java 8:

```
final List<Integer> testList1 = BasicList().getGradeList().stream().map(Test::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
final List<String> testList2 = BasicList().getGradeList().stream().map(Test::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Replace your class name in place of **Test** in above code.

Use below code for below java 8 env:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(BasicList().getGradeList().size());
for (Test test : BasicList().getGradeList()) {
    strings.add(test.getName());
}
```

Similar for Ids.

Comment: thaanqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq <3

Comment: have any other way? becouse thats work but for lower than android 6 dont support **stream**

Comment: If you want to make your method generic for all your models then this is the right way. And if you are below java 8 then you have to use for loop to convert the list.

Comment: <3 thanQ for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need another loop if you want to get all Ids of your models, you can do something like this :

```
List<Integer> listId=new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for(int i=0; i<BasicList().getGradeList().size(); i++) {
                listId.add(findIdByTitle(BasicList().getGradeList().get(i).getID()
                        ,BasicList().getGradeList().get(i).getName()
                        ,spinnerGrade.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            }
```

Comment: Can not find a more simple way?